Prevent systemd from killing processes for all user
This question is related to but not the same as this question. It talks about how to handle this for one user, not all users, automatically.

There are really two parts to this question:

Why is KillUserProcesses=no insufficient to avoid this issue entirely?  Under what circumstances does systemd kill user processes even though this is set to no?  What does lingering actually do when KillUserProcesses=no?
Is there any way to stop this that does not require doing something for every user on the system (the loginctl enable-linger and the KillExcludeUsers setting both need to be done per user)?

At least on my machine, it seems like just the lingering step is necessary and sufficient; the config changes donʼt do anything. Since that is one of the steps required per account, the question still stands. Iʼm also leaving the parts because it seems like other people do find them necessary.
